# How to get logo & Title on same line via bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap & want to get the logo on the left & title in the center. I have used the following code but not able to get the desired result.
Please Guide.

```
<div class="panel-heading"><a href="#">
<img src="Logo.png" width="10%" height="10%" alt="">
</a>
<h1 align="center">Title</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h1 class="text-center"> 
<a class="pull-left" href="#"> 
<img src="path/logo.png" width="10%" height="10%" alt=""> 
</a><span style="margin-left: -20%;">Title</span></h1>
```

try this code.. anything in heading tag would be in one line

Comment: Thank You.It has worked I shifted the logo to left but the heading is not in the center coz of the width of the img.

Comment: use `line-height` @Fresher

Comment: like this `height:30px; line-height:30px;` for vertical center

Comment: `<span class="text-center">Title</span>` for center title use this class

Comment: try that class with h1

Comment: I have tried but the heading is cuming bit on the right side & not centered aligned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104233/discussion-between-fresher-and-gautam-jha).

Answer (score 1):

**Demo**

Add `container-fluid` div along with `pull-left` for `<a>`

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="#" class="pull-left">
      <img src="Logo.png" width="10%" height="10%" alt="">IMG
    </a>
    <h1 align="center">Title</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You will check & let u knw

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="panel-heading">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="pull-left" style="background-color:lavender;">
   <img src="logo.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="">
  </div>
  <h1 align="center">Title</h1></div>
</div>
```

Give pixel size according to your requirement of image.

Comment: always use % not px.